# Firebug and google console both does not let change content rendered through pdf.js why ? and how?

Tags: javascript, firebug, pdf.js, google-console-developer

One can not change content (DOM elements) rendered through pdf.js using firebug and google. How pdf.js achieve this, how can I do the same in my html page

Comment: some dumb people downvote a question just because they can not understand it

Comment: I guess you are talking about the [Firefox DevTools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools), because [Firebug is dead](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2017/10/saying-goodbye-to-firebug/) for quite some time now.

Answer (score 0):

PDF.js renders its output into different `<canvas>` elements (one per page). You can see a small preview of the canvas when using the Firefox DevTools:

[image: Preview of canvas output in Firefox DevTools]

It still generates DOM elements, though, to allow interacting with the contents, i.e. selecting and copying them.